# python program for the DCA logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic, percentage

I'm working on a DCA trading project.  I have some amount 'X' and I need to divide that 'X' amount to 'Y' parts. Each 'Y' part should have scale or ratio of 'Z'. What I want output is 'Y' parts with divided amounts of 'X'

```
X = 1000
Y = 4
Z = 2
```

then output will be

```
66.66, 133.33, 266.66, 533.33
```

Explanation: Each preceding number is double or 2 times (Z) of the previous number and are divided as 4 parts (Y) and their total sum is almost 1000 (X)

Example 2:

```
X = 1000
Y = 5 
Z = 1
```

Then output is

```
200, 200, 200, 200, 200
```

Explanation: Each preceding number is same or 1 times (Z) of the previous number and are divided as 5 parts (Y) and their total sum is almost 1000 (X)

Example 3:

```
X = 1000
Y = 6
Z = 1.5
```

Then output is

```
48.12, 72.18, 108.27, 162.4, 243.6, 365.41
```

Explanation: Each preceding number is almost 1.5 times (Z) of the previous number and are divided as 6 parts (Y) and their total sum is almost 1000 (X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```py
X = 1000
Y = 4
Z = 2

n_parts = sum([Z ** i for i in range(Y)])

part_size = X / n_parts

output = [part_size * Z ** i for i in range(Y)]

print(output)
```

Output:

```py
[66.66666666666667, 133.33333333333334, 266.6666666666667, 533.3333333333334]
```

This code finds the "part size", and then multiplies each output by this to the power of `i`, so the outputs consecutively are Z times bigger than the last.